# Fastest way to write initialization for a list of attributes in Vim

Tags: vim

Sometimes I need to write long block of code which looks like this:

```
a.id = b.id
a.name = b.name
a.host = b.host
a.port = b.port
...
```

Currently I input this by typing the first line, and then for next attibute `yy3pjf.lcw`, typing attribute name, then `f..j` and repeat for next attribute.

But I am wondering if there is a faster ways to input something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution close to what you are already used to, but with fewer keystrokes.

Suppose you start with your first line. Set things up with `E*` followed by `Y3p`.

```
a.id = b.id
a.id = b.id
a.id = b.id
a.id = b.id
```

Now make the changes: `ncename<Esc>` followed by `n.`. `ncehost<Esc>n.`. `nceport<Esc>n.`. Done.

```
a.id = b.id
a.name = b.name
a.host = b.host
a.port = b.port
```

The advantage of this approach is that it comes very naturally: efficient editing with everyday commands. And the overhead of repeated keystrokes is actually quite small.

I often make up such slightly repetitive patterns as I am editing a file. But as soon as such edits come up really often, and you realise that it costs a lot of your time, I suggest taking a more serious approach such as with @IngoKarkat's `:s` command, or @romainl's mapping, or a macro.

Answer (score 7):

If I took the time to think this through beforehand, I would enter this as follows:

```
id
name
host
port
...
```

And then transform the entered lines (`'[,']`) into the desired result:

```
:'[,']s/.*/a.& = b.&/
```

This matches the entire line (`.*`) and uses the result in the replacement via `&`.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that I could use `&` in substitution commands. Someday it will really help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this mapping (`<F6>` is an example):

```
nnoremap <F6> yypww:s/<C-r><C-w>/
```

If you don't have `set gdefault` in your `~/.vimrc`, this one should work:

```
nnoremap <F6> yypww:s/<C-r><C-w>//g<Left><Left>
```

Breakdown:

```
yyp            " duplicate the line
ww             " move to the attribute name
:s/<C-r><C-w>/ " insert the beginning of a :s command using the word under the cursor as pattern
```

In action:

```
a.id = b.id

<F6>name<CR>

a.id = b.id
a.name = b.name
```

Comment: Looks like the fastest to use approach here.

Answer (score 1):

If you go with your copy&paste approach, this can be simplified with my [ChangeGlobally plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4321). On each pasted line, type `ll` (to go to the start of the first `id` part to be replaced, then type `gcename<Esc>`. `gc` is the plugin mapping, `e` means to the *end of word*. After the `<Esc>`, the plugin will automatically change the second / following occurrences.

The copy&paste (`yy3p`) can be simplified with my [LineJuggler plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4140), which has a `]d` command to duplicate lines. The exact equivalent here would be `V3]D` (which isn't shorter, but does not clobber the default register).